# Can you create a Java array of an anonymous class?

Tags: java, arrays, class, anonymous-class

I am wondering if it is possible to create an array of a Java anonymous class. For example, I try this code:

```java
final var anonArray = new Object() {
    public String foo = "bar";
}[4];
```

However that gives an error: `error: array required, but <anonymous Object> found`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `new Object() {...}` gives you a value not a type.

So, here is how you could create an array of instances of anonymous classes:

```
final Object[] anonArray = new Object[]{
     new Object(){
        public String foo = "bar1";
     }, 
     new Object(){
        public String foo = "bar2";
     },
     new Object(){
        public String foo = "bar3";
     },
     new Object(){
        public String foo = "bar4";
     }
};
```

Or if you want an array with the same anonymous class instance 4 times:

```
final Object anonInstance = new Object(){
    public String foo = "bar1";
};
final Object[] anonArray = new Object[]{
     anonInstance, anonInstance, anonInstance, anonInstance
};
```

Or if you want 4 distinct instances of the same anonymous class:

```
final Object[] anonArray = new Object[4];
for (int i = 0; i < anonArray.length; i++) {

    // Just to show we can do this ....
    final String bar = "bar" + 1;

    anonArray[i] = new Object(){
        public String foo = bar;  // Look!
    };
}
```

Note that in all of the above the array type is `Object[]` not "array of the anonymous subclass of `Object`".  It is difficult to conceive that this would matter, but if it did matter you would need to resort to reflection to create the array class.  (See @ernest_k's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65913559/139985).)

Or just declare an array of an appropriate custom class or interface, and create anon subclasses from that class / interface.  Anonymous subclasses of `Object` are not exactly practical ...

Comment: > Remember that new Object() {...} gives you a value not a type. 

Ah, I had completely forgotten. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `new Object() {}` creates an instance of the anonymous class. It does not offer a way to declare an array of the anonymous class.

This should really be discouraged, but if you need to have your anonymous class as the array's component type, you can use `java.lang.reflect.Array`:

```
Object o = new Object() {
    public String foo = "bar";
};

Object[] anonArray = (Object[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(o.getClass(), 4);
anonArray[0] = o;
```

That is probably going to have a hard time passing code review (you can't construct other elements without reflection). So, an alternative: declare a local class in your method:

```
class Anon {
    public String foo = "bar";
};

Anon[] anonArray = new Anon[4];
```

The above `Anon` is local to the method (it's an underused feature of the language)

Comment: I didn't know Java had local classes! I just recently discovered that Kotlin had them after grumbling that `class` is a reserved keyword even in methods, and I was quite surprised there, but damn am I truly surprised to see Java with them. Thank you!